# Add a SUMIF formula to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not good with Macros but I'm trying to use asign a SUMIF formula to a variable but I'm getting error . I need to do this 19 times so if I can get hekp with the 1st one I'll be good

```
    Sub Ejemplo1()
Dim Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8, Value9, Value10, Value11, Value12, Value13, Value14, Value15, Value16, Value17, Value18, Value19, Fila1, Columna1 As Integer
Value20 = ActiveCell
            Fila1 = ActiveCell.Row
            Columna1 = ActiveCell.Column
            Fila1 = Fila1 - 21

Value1 = Value1.Formula = "=SUMIFS(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH($A$1,Table1[#Headers],0)),Table1['#],ActiveCell)"

MsgBox (Value1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the evaluate function: `Value1 = ActiveSheet.Evaluate(...)`

Comment: You should also be aware that you're **not** defining all of those Value1 ... Value19 and Fila1 as `Integers`. You may also want to have a look at defining an `Array` and looping through that.

Comment: I'm confuse , I've tried to use the evaluate but it did not work . The result of that formula is an integer and at the end I would like to sum all the values from Value1 to Value19 and add them on a cell.